# Google maps v2 android error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

Iam trying to fix the problem where we cannot run the google maps api v2 in the emulator for android.
In order to do that i need to push into the emulator some files from the cmd like the GoogleServicesFramework.apk.But when i do so  this error appears

failed to copy 'GoogleLoginService.apk' to '/system/app//GoogleLoginService.apk': Out of memory

Emulator settings:
[image]

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13734937#13734937

Comment: Yes none of them is worikng. See http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4627