# Exception while adding google map to my application

Tags: android

I have done all the steps that have to be followed to add google map to my application. But  still application raises exceptions while compiling.
 I have attached the log file here.

```
08-06 03:45:20.188: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1998): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 3158130
08-06 03:45:20.228: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1998): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 3158130
08-06 03:45:20.268: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1998): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 3158130
08-06 03:45:20.318: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1998): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 3158130
08-06 03:45:20.368: D/dalvikvm(1998): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 250K, 14% free 2770K/3212K, paused 40ms, total 45ms
08-06 03:45:20.388: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1998): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 3158130
08-06 03:45:20.458: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1998): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 3158130
08-06 03:45:20.718: D/gralloc_goldfish(1998): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-06 03:45:24.838: D/AndroidRuntime(1998): Shutting down VM
08-06 03:45:24.838: W/dalvikvm(1998): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
08-06 03:45:24.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1998): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 03:45:24.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1998): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
08-06 03:45:24.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
08-06 03:45:24.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
08-06 03:45:24.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
08-06 03:45:24.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
08-06 03:45:24.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:692)
08-06 03:45:24.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
08-06 03:45:24.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
08-06 03:45:24.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.bb$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
08-06 03:45:24.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
08-06 03:45:24.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
08-06 03:45:24.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-06 03:45:24.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-06 03:45:24.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-06 03:45:24.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-06 03:45:24.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 03:45:24.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-06 03:45:24.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-06 03:45:24.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-06 03:45:24.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 03:45:27.628: I/Process(1998): Sending signal. PID: 1998 SIG: 9
```

Please help me to skip this exception.

Comment: here is a possible solution; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13869332#13869332 (Your google play service is outdated)

Answer (score 0):

First check if you have your Google Play Services updated to latest version and use the most updated version in your project. However, I also found an issue posted on [Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57880). You may follow it to know when the fix is available.