# How to retrieve current device location & show it on map fragment in a fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm developing a android app with google maps. Currently I'm able to view the map inside my app, but I don't know how to view the current location on the app.

Here is my code:

```
public class MapsFragment extends Fragment{
        MapView m;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // inflat and return the layout
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_near_me, container, false);
            m = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
            m.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            return v;
        }
}
```

**Edited:**
And the xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/map" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This code works fine and I got to know 'setmylocationenabled' can help to enable in FragmentActivity, but unfortunately I have to use the type as 'Fragment'. And I'm using google api v2. Please someone help with this.

Comment: We need your google map code !! where do you get the map to manage it ? You should use SupportMapFragment, use the support lib v4 !!

Comment: @Yume117: Made a mistake check my xml code

Comment: instead of MapView use a SupportMapFragment or a Fragment Map :)

Comment: So you use Google map api v1 ? Because this method of displaying map is no longer adviced :/

Comment: So How can i implement it in class type fragment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**How about using the newly introduced fused location provider**
 as referenced from: http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

```
public static class XYZ extends Fragment
            implements
                GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
                GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
                LocationListener {
        GoogleMap map;
        LatLng latlng;
        private LocationRequest lr;
        private LocationClient lc;
        MapFragment mapFragment;
        ImageView iv;
        private static View view;

        public XYZ() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            if (view != null) {
                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                if (parent != null)
                    parent.removeView(view);
            }

            try {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.XYZ, container,
                        false);

                mapFragment = ((MapFragment) this.getActivity()
                        .getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
                iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv);

                map = mapFragment.getMap();
                map.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
                map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

                MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Google Play Services missing !",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (InflateException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Problems inflating the view !",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Google Play Services missing !",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return view;
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            lr = LocationRequest.create();
            lr.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            lc = new LocationClient(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    this, this);
            lc.connect();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location l2) {
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(l2.getLatitude(), l2.getLongitude()), 15);
            map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
            lc.requestLocationUpdates(lr, this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected() {

        }
    }
```

With the XML as:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <fragment
                        android:id="@+id/map"
                        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

**You may get a blank map if you don't have all the requirements,**        https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

1. Get Play services on your project by following this post 
     https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435
2. Then get an api key: https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403
3. Add the permissions to you manifest,

   ```
      <uses-permission android:name="your.application.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
      <uses-permission    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   ```
4. To test the map application you need to have a real device, if not then push play services to emulator via adb, read this post to learn how to install play services via adb https://stackoverflow.com/a/13869332/826657
5. After all steps above, clean your project, uninstall the previous .apk from emulator, and run the project.

Comment: can you please provide your xml as well.

Comment: Getting redflag at getSupportFragmentManager() 'The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Activity'

Comment: i edited the code, try using `getFragmentManager()`, change all `SupportMapFragment` `to MapFragment`, in yur xml too change it to MapFragment from SupportMapFragment

Comment: Sorry for late reply. But I'm getting blank white screen when I run it and in my LogCat: 09-01 13:01:02.760: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(12622): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included. But I added all the required permissions in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I followed all the steps you said and tested on real device. But still same results and the above code (posted by me) shows the map properly. I think there should be some other problems. Need more help please.

Comment: @twnee: in your code I'm changing your code 'public static class XYZ extends Fragment' to 'public class XYZ extends Fragment'. Because It's showing redflag for me. Is that coursing this problem? and can you provide the imports for the XYZ file.

Comment: no that's not causing the problem, actually that was an static inner class inside my fragment activity !, so you got the google play servics to your project.. check... you got the api key and added it to manifest.. check.. you switched on the Android Maps Api from console... check... you added all the permissions to your manifest... check... your real device has the Google Play services.. check... Uninstall the app from real device and try again.

Comment: oki. but how. I don't hav enough reputation chat, may be skype?

Comment: twnee I havn't got any reply on Hangout. And can you answer this question is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558084/how-to-implement-asynctask-in-fragment

Answer (score 7):

You can enable your location just add this code in your class

```
 GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Link explains all the things you need

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map

To set location on Map, you need to use below class

```
LatLong objLatLng=new LatLong(lat,longi);
yourMapObject.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(objLatLng, 20));
yourMapObject.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18), 2000, null);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You should init your Map v2 like this:

```
m = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
GoogleMap mMap = m.getMap();
```

Now you can use `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`

Comment: Tried but force close. CatLog: 08-30 13:26:48.635: D/AndroidRuntime(11455): Shutting down VM
08-30 13:26:48.635: W/dalvikvm(11455): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4164a2a0)
08-30 13:26:48.635: E/AndroidRuntime(11455): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 13:26:48.635: E/AndroidRuntime(11455): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView