# How do I display image using Bitmap and AsyncTask in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap, android-asynctask

I just want to know how to display the image from an URL by using a bitmap and an AsyncTask in a Fragment - not in an Activity.

Comment: use glide or piccaso for load image which loads image fast

Comment: please add what you done till to achieve this!

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add the details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [implement AsyncTask in Fragment android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558084/implement-asynctask-in-fragment-android)

Answer (score 0):

> Use the Piccaso for load image more faster

Picasso.with(context)
  .load(image url here)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)

refer this [link](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

hope this helps.