# Call an AsyncTask method in ActivityMain from fragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment

Previous I haved that AsyncTask on main activity and called with:

```
new SyncGetLocations(ActivityMain.this).execute();
```

Now,I move it to a fragment and don't know now how to call it from `MainActivity`.

AsyncTask look alike :

```
private static class SyncGetLocations extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private WeakReference<ActivityMap> activityReference;

    SyncGetLocations(ActivityMap context) {
        activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

    }
```

}

Comment: review this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558084/implement-asynctask-in-fragment-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Either**

From MainActivity find your fragment:

val fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(...) or findFragmentByID(...)

and then call a method in this fragment to launch the asyncTask

fragent.callAsyncTask()

**Or**

make your asynctask public or remove it from fragment to be its own class and call it froim every where you want

**I suggest you to make asyntask not an inner class of fragment of activity it you wants to call it from everywhere**

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching Listener to your fragment with a method like

```
public interface FragmentInteractionListener{ 
void onClick();
```

}

In your fragment

```
private FragmentInteractionListener fragmentListener;

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    fragmentListener = null;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof FragmentInteractionListener) {
        fragmentListener = (FragmentInteractionListener) context;
    }  else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement FragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

And under onClick event call it like this

```
fragmentListener.onClick();
```

Then in your activity implement the FragmentInteractionListener

OR

```
 ((SomeActivity)getActivity()).someMethod();
```