# Can we run an App with Google Map v2 on Emulator Running Android 4.3?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-maps, google-play-services

It is still not clear if we can test Google Map v2 on Android emulator or **NOT**.

It is all about Play Service and they "Google Android Team" have announced the following:

On [Android-Developer Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/08/google-play-services-32.html) 
They are saying

> To simplify your testing, we've also released an updated Google APIs emulator image that includes Google Play Services 3.2. You can download the image through the Android SDK Manager.

On [Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) They are saying

> To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use either:
>    •A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.2 or higher and includes Google Play Store.
>   •The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.

But, I still not able to run the Map on Android Emulator with Google API 18 (4.3).

What is the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't possible initially, but it seems the new version of the google play services apk is making it possible.

Check out the answer here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13734937#13734937)

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to try it out myself.