# Failed to install Map.apk on device 'emulator-5554'

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm new to the Android world, and I need to create an app using Google Maps Android API. I follow the instructions in:

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start
```

and whenever I start the AVD I get an error:

```
[2013-12-05 21:04:37 - Map] Failed to install Map.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2013-12-05 21:04:37 - Map] (null)
[2013-12-05 21:04:38 - Map] Launch canceled!
```

My MainActivity code:

```
package com.example.map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

my MainActivity XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

and my Manifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.map"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.xxxxxxxxxHIDDENxxxxxxxx"
    android:value="xxxxxxxxxHIDDENxxxxxxxx"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.map.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Also tried the code that it's provided here:

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/
```

being the MainActivity file code:

```
package com.example.map;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

        // Get a handle to the Map Fragment
        GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Sydney")
                .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
                .position(sydney));
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: please post the stack trace

Comment: The errors I posted are the only ones that appear in the Console View. On LogCat it has a lot of lines!

Comment: search for the line where the actual `Exception` starts

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would recommend is to not show your API key to the public; this are supposed to be private to whomever is developing the application.

Also the format of this meta tag is wrong:

```
   <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.AIzaSyB7AMKbYsVajgb6D0zpq9wUODX9gdR2DhE"
    android:value="AIzaSyB7AMKbYsVajgb6D0zpq9wUODX9gdR2DhE"/>
```

You are copying your API key at the end of the name. I strongly suggest you create a new API key and do not use this one that you have exposed to the public. There might be other errors, but without the stack trace is hard to say.

Comment: damn! you're right, I was very distracted. Key deleted and I created a new one

Answer (score 0):

See this page: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Specifically:

> To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use
>   either:
>
> - A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.3 or higher and    includes Google Play Store.
> - The Android emulator with an AVD that    runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.

So make sure the emulator you're using is Android 4.2.2 or greater. If it is below this level, Google Play Services is not available on the emulator, and you must use a physical android device to test it out.

If you have to test on a lower-end device emulator, there are workarounds to this but they aren't officially supported by Google so your mileage may vary.

See this link:
[Custom emulator that supports Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13734937#13734937)

Comment: I'm using an emulator of Android 4.4 and I'm targeting the 4.2.2, 4.3 and 4.4 versions

Comment: In that case, try executing  
**adb kill-server**, then **adb start-server**  
through command prompt from the /platform-tools folder in your android-sdk folder.