# Error on using the maps library

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to run android maps example on my emulator, I have added the library

```
  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

inside the application tag.

When I try to run the application in emulator I get the following error

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
```

I have set the build path for android to "Google API's"

How to resolve this error?

Comment: looks like you are using map api v1 which is deprecated. switch to api v2. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: I am using api v2 itself.

Comment: Did you include `google-play-service_lib` to your project?

Comment: then uses-library is not required in that case. all you need  to do is reference google play services library project

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can't run google maps v2 on emulator.

You can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13734937#13734937) for a dirty solution

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project --> Properties --> Android --> On the library block clik on add and add google-play-services_lib as your project's library. Then to your manifest file add:

```
<permission
    android:name="your_package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="your_package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

Then in your application tag add:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing the app in emulator make sure that `You have created AVD for emulator with Google Maps-APIs`.

In general, this error arises from the fact that Google Maps not installed on your device/emulator.