# Google Play Services not working on Android Emulator?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-emulator, google-play-services

I am making the app that use Google Maps, but I can not show it, because I get error this error.

I am using Nexus 5 API 22 Emulator.

Here is screenshot of emulator settings.

[image]

Here is screenshot of emulator.

[image]

Comment: You can try Genymotion. It has possibility to install Google Apps.
https://www.genymotion.com

Comment: I guess you should update your google play services library in android sdk manager. Another thing you should try is to update google play in your emulator.

Comment: Yeah, I know for Genymotion, but I want original Andorid Emulator.

Comment: Updating Google Play Services did not help.

Comment: And when I check for Google Play version it is 6.7, and that is too old, but I do not have update button.

Comment: @Zookey. If you really want to test your app on emulator and you don't have a real device, then play with your issue else I would highly recommend not to bother with emulator, rather test on real device. I had really much harder time with emulator and Google play services to work together,even with geny motion. I've ended with installing gapps and the other arm translating zip files on geny motion, but hardly got anything running without furthermore issues.

Comment: Try downloading one of the newer version of Google Play Services in apk form onto your computer and dumping in onto your emulator (drag and drop I believe).

Comment: Have you had a chance to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450007/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-error)?