# Best Route between two location with multiple waypoints in Google Map Android studio

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm making an android studio application in which a user can see the best sortest paths between two location points. I use Normal android studio map frame and SupportMapFragment to show google map.I want to find the best route in multiple waypoints.These are the file of my android application. only one issue in this project file MapsActivity.java file getmap method is not working. is there any other way develop this one?

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        GoogleMap map;
        ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

            // Initializing
            markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

            // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting reference to Button
            Button btnDraw = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_draw);

            // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
            map = fm.getMap();

            // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Setting onclick event listener for the map
            map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                    // Already 10 locations with 8 waypoints and 1 start location and 1 end location.
                    // Upto 8 waypoints are allowed in a query for non-business users
                    if(markerPoints.size()>=10){
                        return;
                    }

                    // Adding new item to the ArrayList
                    markerPoints.add(point);

                    // Creating MarkerOptions
                    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

                    // Setting the position of the marker
                    options.position(point);

                    /**
                     * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
                     * for the end location, the color of marker is RED and
                     * for the rest of markers, the color is AZURE
                     */
                    if(markerPoints.size()==1){
                        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                    }else if(markerPoints.size()==2){
                        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                    }else{
                        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
                    }

                    // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
                    map.addMarker(options);
                }
            });

            // The map will be cleared on long click
            map.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
                    // Removes all the points from Google Map
                    map.clear();

                    // Removes all the points in the ArrayList
                    markerPoints.clear();
                }
            });

            // Click event handler for Button btn_draw
            btnDraw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
                    if(markerPoints.size() >= 2){
                        LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
                        LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

                        // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                        String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                        // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                        downloadTask.execute(url);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

            // Origin of route
            String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

            // Destination of route
            String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

            // Sensor enabled
            String sensor = "sensor=false";

            // Waypoints
            String waypoints = "";
            for(int i=2;i<markerPoints.size();i++){
                LatLng point  = (LatLng) markerPoints.get(i);
                if(i==2)
                    waypoints = "waypoints=";
                waypoints += point.latitude + "," + point.longitude + "|";
            }

            // Building the parameters to the web service
            String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor+"&"+waypoints;

            // Output format
            String output = "json";

            // Building the url to the web service
            String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

            return url;
        }

        /** A method to download json data from url */
        private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
            String data = "";
            InputStream iStream = null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
            }finally{
                iStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Fetches data from url passed
        private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

            // Downloading data in non-ui thread
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

                // For storing data from web service

                String data = "";

                try{
                    // Fetching the data from web service
                    data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
                }
                return data;
            }

            // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
            // doInBackground()
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

                // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
                parserTask.execute(result);
            }


        }

        /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
        private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> > {

            // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
            @Override
            protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

                JSONObject jObject;
                List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

                try{
                    jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                    DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                    // Starts parsing data
                    routes = parser.parse(jObject);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return routes;
            }

            // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {

                ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
                PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

                // Traversing through all the routes
                for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                    points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                    lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                    // Fetching i-th route
                    List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                    // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                    for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                        HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                        double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                        double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                        LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                        points.add(position);
                    }

                    // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                    lineOptions.addAll(points);
                    lineOptions.width(2);
                    lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
                }

                // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
                map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
            }
        }
        }
```

other file DirectionsJSONParser.java

```
public class DirectionsJSONParser {

    /**
     * Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude
     */
    public List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {

        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String, String>>>();
        JSONArray jRoutes = null;
        JSONArray jLegs = null;
        JSONArray jSteps = null;

        try {

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing all routes */
            for (int i = 0; i < jRoutes.length(); i++) {
                jLegs = ((JSONObject) jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for (int j = 0; j < jLegs.length(); j++) {
                    jSteps = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for (int k = 0; k < jSteps.length(); k++) {
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for (int l = 0; l < list.size(); l++) {
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng) list.get(l)).latitude));
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng) list.get(l)).longitude));
                            path.add(hm);
                        }
                    }
                    routes.add(path);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return routes;
    }

    /**
     * Method to decode polyline points
     * Courtesy : jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
     */
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
}
```

other file activity_maps.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_draw"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/btn_draw" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get map, use this:

```
// Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Your activity must implement `OnMapReadyCallback` and override `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` function.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{
     .....

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

   }

 }
```

See [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start) guide.

Comment: when i use this one and run the project it's automatically closed. any other way ?

Comment: What's an error ? See the error in Log (Android Monitor window).

Comment: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded like this android monitor some error coming

Comment: Well, this error has nothing to do with Maps neither your code shows anything like this.

Comment: what is this one "my application won't run unless you update google play services". then open it and show this massage and update button.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450007/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-error