# Unable to run Google map in application running in Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, kotlin, android-8.0-oreo

I am receiving error:

> AppName won't run unless you update Google Play services.
>
> Update

Emulator is not showing option for updating Google Play Services.

---

### Configurations

**Emulator:**

- Android 8.1 (Oreo)
- Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image.

**Following is installed:**

- Build tools 27.0.3
- Android Emulator 27.2.0
- Google Play Services (Version 48)

Android Studio 3.1 Canary 9 running on Ubuntu.

Tried many solutions on this website but no success.

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450007/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Use That Emulator Which have Playstore Like this shown in Image.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't Google Map run even of those without Play Store in them? Google Maps require only Google Play system image. Right?

Comment: you are using Play services in your app so you will Run only in the Device which have PlaySevices

Answer (score 1):

Now even better solution exist: using AVD image with build-in Google Play Services. It will enable you to use Google Services including Google Play. Also you will be able update it without re-creating AVD image.

[image]

For further information check this post

https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536595/how-to-download-google-play-services-in-an-android-emulator&ved=2ahUKEwjwz76G5u7ZAhUMCuwKHdVFAH4QFjADegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw1NNhhmar8bv8PoXT5o9B0q

Answer (score 0):

You must have an Emulator with Google APIs included. Depending in the version of Google Play Services libraries used in your project you may require a higher API level emulator with Google API included.
An emulator with Android 8.0 (API level 26) with Google API (Google Play) included should be enough.

[Like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OI6iJ.png)