# How to update google play in android

Tags: android, google-play

Good Noon to all

I'm developing an application which is based on accessing google account for login purpose of my own appplication.

If i run my application means it throws an error as

"Google Play services out of date. Requires 4452000 but found 3136130"

here is my screen shot

[image: This is the screen shot for the google play updation via sdkmanager]

Comment: Update your google play services from SDK Manager.

Comment: already updated that goole play like wise only but there is no change....it keeps on throws the above mentioned error

Comment: You updated play services but you need to copy-paste that lib into your `Workspace`?

Comment: ya i coied that in workspace also and also added to library but no use...still biting the nail

Comment: I have the same problem (except it's 4452000 and 4242032). It was all working in my emulator and then it stopped, I think after running the SDK manager which found updates. What I've done so far is updating via the SDK manager, removed the imported old version and imported the new version but that doesn't help. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13869332#13869332] was how I got it working in the first place. I wonder if the solution is to update com.google.android.gms-20140218.apk with a newer version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem, solution (for Eclipse) was:

1. remove local copy of google play service from workspace
2. open Android SDK Manager
3. delete google play service
4. install google play service
5. add local copy of google play service to workspace

Done!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried creating new emulators with the normal API levels (tried 17 and 19) and adding the apk from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13869332#13869332) but it doesn't seems to work after the update. I did get it to work though by creating an emulator using the Google API level 19.

To get it to work I think you need to do (assuming Eclipse):

- Window->Android SDK Manager and make sure all is up to date.
- Update the google play library you've imported to your Workbench
- Create a new device (after updating) with Target Google API lvl 19

Then start the emulator and install your app. For me that made the map work. I think your problem is that you've updated the google play library to the newest while you created the emulator before that. Then it doesn't have the version installed you are using in your project.

Comment: I tried it but no use of it still i couldn't resolve it

Answer (score 0):

If you search `Google play Services` in the google play store, you will find an app by google you have to download to get this functionality. If you have any problems, here's the link:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=nl

Comment: @Appdev right... you should try a newer emulator to get this functionality then, I think..