# "Unfortunately, My Map has stopped" error

Tags: android

I am getting this error "Unfortunately, My Map has stopped" on my phone whenever I try to run this application ("My Map" is the name of the application ).

my google_services is version 17

does anyone know how can I fix this?

**solution:**after 2 frustrating days I found the solution for the problem:

so it's not enough to add this to the manifest file as a son of the application tag:

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
          android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/app_key"/> //app_key is the value of my api key
```

you should also have the integer initialized to 4452000 and not 4132500 as I someone said in another post. (this can be added to the string folder)

```
 <integer name="google_play_services_version">4452000</integer>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.seminarion.shiran;



import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
GoogleMap mMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(servicesOK()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

//this method checking whether the google play kit services are installed in the device of the user and 
//letting the user know his current status. 

public boolean servicesOK() {
    int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    //IF I get a value of success that's mean googlePlay services is installed
    //and we can display a map
    if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();
    }
    else {
        //error which is not recoverd by the user . we simply show the user an error message
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to Google Play services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.seminarion.shiran"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
         android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission android:name="com.seminarion.shiran.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.seminarion.shiran.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.provider.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"
/>

<uses-feature
 android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
 android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.seminarion.shiran.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="Here is my key..." //API KEY 

          />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />        
 </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat:

```
 05-27 12:54:46.205: D/AndroidRuntime(10437): Shutting down VM
05-27 12:54:46.205: W/dalvikvm(10437): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught     exception (group=0x40ff4930)
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start        activity ComponentInfo{com.seminarion.shiran/com.seminarion.shiran.MainActivity}:    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does  not have the right value.  Expected 4452000 but found 4132500.  You must have the following  declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data  android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:151)
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437): Caused by:      java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4452000 but found 4132500.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.t(Unknown Source)
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437):    at com.seminarion.shiran.MainActivity.servicesOK(MainActivity.java:40)
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437):    at com.seminarion.shiran.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
05-27 12:54:46.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10437):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: update your google play services i guess its rev 17 now

Comment: what is integer/google_play_services_version?

Comment: this is something I read here as aolution to this kind of problem.. but it didn't help..it's in my Strings

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not set the google-play-version on your own. It is already specified in the google-play-service project under res/values/version.xml

Try to reinstall the google-play-service instead (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24152276/1885518) or simply to update via the SDK-Manager if not already down.