# with fragment google maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm trying my hand and Android Application Development. I'm currently using Eclipse (I can't remember the version, whatever the newest is). I've crossed a bridge where I just can't seem to grasp what I'm doing wrong. I'm attempting to use the Google Maps V2 API. I've been through several documents and tried several techniques, all of which lead to the same error
 `Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment``

I've tried so many different answers from questions similar to mine, but to no avail. :( I can usually figure these things out, but maybe I'm just too overloaded.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVISES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="---my key----" />
</application>
```

`

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.testing.svma.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

`public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private GoogleMap  map;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    map = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
}`
```

Comment: Code matter a lot!!! My friend!!! So post it..

Comment: please use some words to explain the problem, and few lines of code to understand till now how much you did.

Comment: there is the code thanx for the help

Comment: Keep secret your MAP KEY...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Change the map fragment name as follows,

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

And put these in to your manifest file also,

```
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: there is no error now but this message "this app won't run unless you update google play services" and a button "update

Comment: have you installed the latest google play services on your device ?

Comment: there is no update available freind i tried to uninstall and install it  and it's the same thing

Comment: just to refine, i hope you are using a real device ?? not the emulator ?

Comment: but emulator is not supported for Map V2

Comment: but i saw in some tutorial they run this app with the emulator

Comment: please try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13734937#13734937