# App won't run unless you update google play services - Android Studio

Tags: android, dictionary, emulation

Im currently using android studio 1.5. My problem is when I try to run my google maps activity in my emulator, it kept showing the prompt "App wont run unless you update google play services". What now?

Here is my Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android 
{
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig 
{
    applicationId "com.farmmanagementsystem.farmmanagementapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes 
{
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services (via Bazaar)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar)

Comment: Maybe the playservices version is older than 8.3.0 in the device ? try compiling with older playservices gradle

Comment: thank you @Dhina, but can you please explain it to me further? Like how to do it? Thank you!

Comment: you can try with play-services:7.0.0. Although i don't think it'll help with emulators that don't have google play installed

Comment: Yup or try with GenyMotion. Install and create a virtual device of any API version.  you can download zip online for that particular API and just drag and drop the zip to the device