# Google play services problems in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services

I'm doing a map activity, but when I run it in the emulator this problem appears: "this app won't work unless you upgrade your Google Play Services".

App Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "chris.touristmap"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 24
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
    }
```

and the gradle application :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="chris.touristmap">

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: please see this, i hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar

Comment: i dont understand much of this answer but thank you anyway ^^

Comment: and i have windows 8.1 its a problem with windows?

Comment: Not really a duplicate, because with previous version 9.6.1 it was just working fine with emulator, but with 9.8.0 the google maps won't work anymore.

Comment: is genymotion's emulator working yet with the new version of google play?